# Drools windowing triggered more then once

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, drools-fusion

I want to trigger the rule if there are two events of same type happened in the same place over the window of 10 seconds.

I have the following rule:

```
  rule "trigger if there were more then 2 events of same type in same place"
  when
    $event1: Event($props : props, $props.get("EVENT_TYPE") == "FOO_TYPE", $props.containsKey("EVENT_PLACE"))
    $eventPlace1: String() from $props.get("EVENT_PLACE")
    $events: List(size > 2) from collect(Event($props2 : props,
                                                       $props2.get("EVENT_TYPE") == "FOO_TYPE",
                                                       $props2.containsKey("EVENT_PLACE"),
                                                       $props2.get("EVENT_DATE") == $eventPlace1
                                                      ) over window:time(10s))
  then
    System.out.println("rule triggered, the events are: " + $events);
end
```

The field `props` in Event is `Map<String, Object>`.

The issue is that this rule gets triggered multiple times instead of once.

For example I'm inserting 4 events, where 3 of them are eligible for this rule e.g. they have same EVENT_TYPE and EVENT_PLACE.

I'm expecting that rule will be fired once, but in reality in fires 3 times, once for each eligible event.

How to achieve the desired behavior ?

Comment: Did you try the above rule definition by merging them with **and (&&)** condition? is the result is same?

Comment: @Prog_G thank you, I've tried as you suggested, but no success